# In a table, add property to a cell in a column which include a cell containing a specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table as shown:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="td1166">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Number</td>
   <td>A</td>
   <td>B</td> //Assume that this cell indicate the column I need to select
   <td>C</td>
   <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td> //So the last cell in the 'A' column is the one I want to add property, and A is known.
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

All the need I have presented in the code.
I was trying using jQuery but I have no idea how to select as such. Hope your kind help!

Comment: what do you mean by selecting?

Comment: I mean this top cell indicates this column and I want to select the bottom column bro.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this, note: this will only work for the first and last rows, you will need different selectors  if you have different rows

```js
$('tr:first td').each(function(i,v){
  if($(this).text() == "B") {
    var index = $(v).index();//get the index of the colomn
    $('tr:last td').eq(index).css('color','red');//select the element
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="td1166">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td> <!--//Assume that this cell indicate the column I need to select-->
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>here</td><!-- //So the last cell in the 'A' column is the one I want to add property, and A is known.-->
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I can't get the function, what does it really mean by the parameter (i,v) ?

Comment: In my thoughts, the parameters save the index and the elment, do they?